# nfdc register command in NDN

Tags: linux, ubuntu-14.04, lxc

I am using NDN (Named Data Networking tool). I have installed ndn and nfd on two linux container nodes with ip addresses. 10.0.0.1 and 10.0.0.2. The two nodes can ping each other. However, after starting nfd + nrd on the nodes, I get the following output whenever I try to register node (with ip address 10.0.0.2) on node (with ip address 10.0.0.1) :

The connection is successful but just after that the connection gets closed.

Any insight to this problem would be highly appreciated.

Regards

root@left:/# nfdc register /ndn udp://10.0.0.2
1438861626.287938 INFO: [FaceTable] Added face id=69115 remote=fd://20 local=unix:///run/nfd.sock
1438861626.296786 WARNING: [FaceTable] Trying to add existing face id=66638 to the face table
**Successful in name registration**: ControlParameters(Name: /ndn, FaceId: 66638, Origin: 255, Cost: 0, Flags: 1, )
**1438861626.318731 INFO: [UnixStreamFace] [id:69115,uri:fd://20] Connection closed
root@left:/# 1438861626.324441 INFO: [FaceTable] Removed face id=69115 remote=fd://20 local=unix:///run/nfd.sock**

Answer (score 0):

You are successful in name registration. The other messages you see are just internal messages from NFD (If you exit your terminal and reopen another one to do nfdc register, you would not see those. Or you can set the log level in nfd.conf to NONE). You can check that the registration is successful by issuing the command nfd-status and finding the name /ndn in the FIB (You can also issue nfd-status -b to get only the FIB).

Please use the NFD mailing list to get quick responses to your questions http://www.lists.cs.ucla.edu/mailman/listinfo/nfd-dev